# How would make it so I can apply a button to any window I want?

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter

I had trouble wording the question so let me explain. I am learning to use Object Oriented Programming as part of a project, so I decided to start off by creating classes for creating windows and buttons to place on the windows (Labels ect. will come later too). In other words, I want to be able to place button on a "Window1" without specifying "Window1" in the class (and instead pass it through with the CreateButton(values). Here is my code so far, and help is appreaciated. PS. It functioned how it should before I tried the windowname parameter, and I set the window manually to home_window, but I cant seem to get the windowname paramater to pass through properly.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

home_window = tk.Tk()
home_window.title("Rota System")
home_window.geometry("600x600")

def thankyou():
    print ("Thank you very much")

class CreateWindow():
    def __init__(self, name, title, geometry):
        self.name = name
        self.title = title
        self.geometry = geometry

        name = tk.Tk()
        name.title(title)
        name.geometry(geometry)



class CreateButton():
    def __init__(self, name, width, height, x, y, font, size, text, command, windowname):
    #I want to be able to place the button on any window I want, not just home_window
        self.name = name
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.font = font
        self.size = size
        self.text = text
        self.command = command
        self.windowname = windowname

        name = tk.Button(windowname, text=text, command=command)
        name.config(font=(font, size))
        name.place(x=x, y=y, height=height, width=width)

CreateWindow("Test", "Test", "900x600")
CreateButton("Test","200","200","0","0","Courier",10,"Test",thankyou, "Test")
```

Comment: Why don't you inherit from `tk.Button`? Or a `tk.Frame`?

Comment: btw those `()` parentheses are not necessary if not inheriting from anything, just use `class ClassName:`, tho if You were to inherit then use `class ClassName(InheritFrom):` and don't forget to either in the `__init__` method use `super().__init__()` or `InheritFrom.__init__(self)` (tho maybe it is vice versa with those `self`)

Comment: when you create any widget in Tkinter you have to set `parent` as first argument - so it knows where to display it. And you should do the same with your classes - `win = CreateWindow(...)` and `CreateButton(win, ...)` But you should rather inherit classes `CreateWindow(tk.Tk)` and `CreateButton(tk.Button)` to get it. Or you should rather create functions `create_window()`, `create_button()` which uses `return name` and because your code better fit to functions. And names with word `create` also rather fit to functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: `tkinter` needs object's ID returned by `Tk()`, `Button()`, etc. - not names (strings) which you created.

With string names you would have to keep global dictionary `{name: object_id}` to convert `name` to `object_id`.

---

**BTW:**

`Tk()` should be used only to create main window. For other windows you should use `Toplevel()`

---

Your code in classes (and they names) rather fit to functions.

Function creates object and use `return` to return this object so it can be used in other function.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# --- functions ---

def thank_you():
    print ("Thank you very much")

def create_window(title, geometry):
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title(title)
    window.geometry(geometry)
    
    return window

def create_button(parent, width, height, x, y, font, size, text, command):

    button = tk.Button(parent, text=text, command=command)
    button.config(font=(font, size))
    button.place(x=x, y=y, height=height, width=width)

    return button

# --- main ---

window = create_window("Test", "900x600")
button = create_button(window, 200, 200, 0, 0, "Courier", 10, "Test", thank_you)

window.mainloop()
```

---

Using classes I would inherit it. So I can assing instance to variable and use in other class as parent.

And I would use `nouns` as names for classes.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# --- classes ---

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    
    def __init__(self, name, title, geometry):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.name = name

        self.title(title)
        self.geometry(geometry)

        #self._title = title
        #seff._geometry = geometry


class MyButton(tk.Button):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, name, width, height, x, y, font, size, text, command):
        super().__init__(parent, text=text, command=command)
        
        self.name = name

        self.config(font=(font, size))
        self.place(x=x, y=y, height=height, width=width)
        
        #self._width = width
        #self._height = height
        #self._x = x
        #self._y = y
        #self._font = font
        #self._size = size
        #self._text = text
        #self._command = command


# --- functions ---

def thank_you():
    print("Thank you very much")

# --- main ---

window = MainWindow("WindowName", "Test", "900x600")
button = MyButton(window, "ButtonName", 200, 200, 0, 0, "Courier", 10, "Test", thank_you)

window.mainloop()
```

---

See: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) -

I don't know if there is about `nouns` for class names and `verbs` for functions (or maybe it was in book `Clean Code, Robert C. Martin`) but usually people use this rule.